# Issue on zoom inside a d3.js chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using on d3.js, and it's working fine.But i'm not figuring out to insert zoom. I'm using a snippet to inser the zoom inside the chart.

this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.dot {
  stroke: #35353a;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 40, right: 50, bottom: 60, left: 70},
    width = 1060 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom;



var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();


var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.tsv("data/test.tsv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = +d.y;
    d.x = +d.x;
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.x; })).nice();
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.y; })).nice();

  svg.append("rect")
    .style('fill', 'transparent')
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("x", width)
      .attr("y", -6)
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("1° Principal Component");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("class", "label")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("2° Principal Component")

  svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", 3.5)
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.cluster); });

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

});

</script>
```

if I insert the code to zoom, i'm not able to see the graph again:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.right + ")")
    .call(zoom);-> add zoom to svg

function zoomed() {
  container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

what's wrong?

little snippet of tsv:

```
x   y   cluster
-1.0403321821456555 -0.9975352942962847 1 Cluster
-1.0404728255519613 -1.0021499065423058 1 Cluster
-1.0405312135780753 -1.0036348433263207 1 Cluster
-1.0405417259454817 -0.9883123582794969 1 Cluster
-1.0406344016908704 -0.9988259809896288 1 Cluster
-1.0406850822323188 -1.004030268612692  1 Cluster
-1.0406958447337742 -1.0065636473623911 1 Cluster
-1.0408667295862442 -1.0046081788513885 1 Cluster
-1.0408845367165218 -0.995137367062602  1 Cluster
-1.040932294864444  -0.991519347648691  1 Cluster
-1.040976952803462  -0.9833995692226501 1 Cluster
-1.0409896369345166 -0.9951495809699621 1 Cluster
-1.0410051379794218 -0.99448305469843   1 Cluster
-1.0410265061033306 -0.9951333768928067 1 Cluster
-1.0410330574179099 -0.9949308462686461 1 Cluster
-1.0410357249485886 -1.0053243527321372 1 Cluster
-1.0410491702402065 -1.006726904241483  1 Cluster
-1.041049812593761  -0.9865506278675225 1 Cluster
-1.0410667719605575 -0.9911033214658317 1 Cluster
-1.0411116340142055 -0.9735253204825465 1 Cluster
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: can you also post the contents of ur tsv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am playing blind here as I don't have a running code:

```
function zoomed() {
  container.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

This should have been:

```
function zoomed() {
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

Explanation: I see the code does not have a container; the translate should be on the g group appended to svg.

Comment: thanks... this was a distraction error. now works! is there a way to zoom in/out the elements inside the plot, instead of the plot?

Comment: Here we are zooming on the full g or group which holds the full chart. for some particular g on which you want to add teh zoom add the call zoom to that element.

Comment: can you provide me a little example?, if i want to zoom on elements, let's say, like jfreechart..